# django how to use prefetch_related() to fetch a foreignkey's related_name

Tags: django

django how to use prefetch_related() to fetch a foreignkey's related_name

```py
class B(models.Models):
    pass

class A(models.Models):

    b = models.ForeignKey(B)


class C(models.Models):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='related_c')
```

Expected result:
I tried like this, but failed

```py
a_data = A.objects.prefetch_related('b__related_c')

for a in a_data:
    all_c_by_b = a.b.related_c.all()

    c_obj = all_c_by_b.first()
    # i dont want hit database
    print(c_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your query like this:-

```
A.objects.all().prefetch_related('b') # this is how you can use prefetch_related
```

If you want to get all the C model record, then the query is :-

```
c_result = C.objects.all()
```

then you can get all the B model data from the same query result

```
b_data = c_result.related_c.all() # here is how you can get all the B model records
```

So, accordingly you have to write or design your model classes

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question: what's the correct string parameter to pass to prefetch related, to prefetch all C's to the respective B's results without running into N+1 problem